# How to convert a PKCS#8 encoded RSA key into PKCS#1 in Java?

Tags: java, security, rsa, jce, pkcs#8

Is it possible to convert a PKCS#8 encoded RSA private key into PKCS#1?
I know this can be done easily via openssl, but can it be done in Java?

Comment: take a look at bouncy castle http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use BouncyCastle 1.50

```
PrivateKeyInfo pkInfo = PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(pkPair.getPrivateKey().getEncodedKey());
ASN1Encodable privateKeyPKCS1ASN1Encodable = pkInfo.parsePrivateKey();
ASN1Primitive privateKeyPKCS1ASN1 = privateKeyPKCS1ASN1Encodable.toASN1Primitive();

byte[] privateKeyPKCS1 = privateKeyPKCS1ASN1.getEncoded();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `KeyFactory` with `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` (algorithm `"RSA"`) to convert the PKCS #8 encoded private key bytes into Java objects.

Use `Cipher` and `SecretKeyFactory` (algorithm `"PBEWithMD5AndDES"`) with `PBEKeySpec`, and `PBEParameterSpec`  to create PKCS #5 encoded stuff.