# How to convert java.security.PrivateKey object to org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey object

Tags: java, rsa, private-key

everyone!
When I try to convert a java.security.PrivateKey object to an org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey object, like the code show.

```
void prvKey2BCRSAPrvKey() throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    System.out.println(privateKey.getAlgorithm());
    RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = RSAPrivateKey.getInstance(privateKey.getEncoded());
    System.out.println(rsaPrivateKey.getVersion());
}
```

I always get an error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer
>
> at org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey.(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey.getInstance(Unknown Source)

I know the problem is happening here.

```
RSAPrivateKey.getInstance(privateKey.getEncoded())
```

And more deep reason is in this function which is in org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPrivateKey:

```
private RSAPrivateKey(ASN1Sequence var1) {
    Enumeration var2 = var1.getObjects();
    ASN1Integer var3 = (ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement();
    int var4 = var3.intValueExact();
    if (var4 >= 0 && var4 <= 1) {
        this.version = var3.getValue();
        this.modulus = ((ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement()).getValue();
        this.publicExponent = ((ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement()).getValue();
        this.privateExponent = ((ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement()).getValue();
        this.prime1 = ((ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement()).getValue();
        this.prime2 = ((ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement()).getValue();
        this.exponent1 = ((ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement()).getValue();
        this.exponent2 = ((ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement()).getValue();
        this.coefficient = ((ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement()).getValue();
        if (var2.hasMoreElements()) {
            this.otherPrimeInfos = (ASN1Sequence)var2.nextElement();
        }

    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong version for RSA private key");
    }
}
```

When the code runs here, it goes wrong.

```
ASN1Integer var3 = (ASN1Integer)var2.nextElement();
```

But I don't know how to fix it.
It is some code I write is wrong?
I use java1.8 and the BC dependent libraries is

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.70</version>
    </dependency>
```

Someone can help me?
Very very thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java `PrivateKey.getEncoded()` returns the PKCS8 encoding of the key.** This is in the javadoc for the *superclass* [`java.security.Key`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Key.html#getFormat()), admittedly not the most obvious place to look.
With Bouncy, you can decode the PKCS8 using `org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo` and extract the algorithm-specific part, which for RSA is the (PKCS1) RSAPrivateKey structure, and *that* is what you should feed to `org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs1.RSAPrivateKey.getInstance` -- you can use any of the `ASN1Encodable` returned from `parsePrivateKey`, the `ASN1Sequence` underlying it, or the `byte[]` returned by `.getEncoded`.

Compare [How to convert a PKCS#8 encoded RSA key into PKCS#1 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271189/how-to-convert-a-pkcs8-encoded-rsa-key-into-pkcs1-in-java) and maybe [PEM encoding of ECDSA in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777264/pem-encoding-of-ecdsa-in-java) (which is for ECC instead of RSA but the principle is the same; disclosure: my answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have solved the problem according to the idea you provided.